# Incorrect memory leak in purify?

Tags: c++, delete-operator, purify

I ran purify on my code which runs in Solaris and it shows lot of memory leaks.
But I checked the code and most of the leaks seem to be invalid.

For eg,

**File1.cpp**

```
Obj* getMyObj()
{
    Obj* obj = NULL;
    if(condition)
    {
        obj = new Obj();   //Purify is reporting leak here
        //Fill obj
    }

    ...
    return obj;
}
```

**File2.cpp**

```
void myfunc()
{
    Obj* myobj = getMyObj();

   if(myobj == NULL)
       return;
    ...
    ...

    delete myobj;    //The object is deleted here
}
```

Even though the object is destroyed properly in `File2.cpp`, why is purify reporting leak in `File1.cpp`?

**EDIT**

The NULL check was just a typo, I corrected it.

Comment: Ar you showing all your code? Is this a factory function where you build different objects depending on the "condition"? In that case, do class Obj have a virtual destructor?

Comment: @NiklasKarlsson - This is not a factory function. But, the class Obj has a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Even though the object is destroyed properly in File2.cpp, [...]

This assumption is wrong.

```
Obj* myobj = getMyObj();
```

If `getMyObj` actually creates an object, it won't return a null pointer. That means the condition in the following `if` is true, and then the function returns immediately.

```
if(myobj)
    return;
```

No further code executes in that function, so it's never destroyed.

I recommend the use of smart pointers instead of this kind of manual management, as this kind of errors just goes away. With C++11 you can use `std::unique_ptr`, otherwise you can use `std::auto_ptr` if you're careful.

Comment: @DeadMG - What does one do, if he does not have access to `boost` or `C++11`?

Comment: @cppcoder Write your own smart pointer class. Something like boost's shared_ptr is straightforward enough, even though you're unlikely to do it quite as well as the boost devs did.

Comment: @jahhaj `shared_ptr` is far from straightforward, unless you mean it's straightforward to write a buggy one. `auto_ptr` is fine if you're careful and don't drop it on containers and the like.

Comment: @R.Martinho Fernandes Hmm, what kind of bugs are you thinking of? Reference counted smart pointers is a topic well covered in books etc.

Comment: @jahhaj: Feel free to try and drop it in for code review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions were we will be sure to point out the problems. Smart pointers are some of the hardest things to get correct and the boost guys spent years getting it working correctly.

Comment: @LokiAstari Hmm, I think I'll pass and just use boost. But the OP is not able to do this, I was just pointing out that it should be possible for him to write a smart pointer class that is adequate for his needs. That is certainly a better route than attempting to use raw pointers.

Comment: @jahhaj: std::auto_ptr would be a far better choice than writing your own.

Comment: @LokiAstari But only if std:auto_ptr is adequate for his needs. I find it very limited and therefore I've never used it much.

Comment: @jahhaj: Its exactly std::unique_ptr (apart from you don't use std::move). Even if it was not adequate its still better than anything we could write.

Comment: It's exactly `unique_ptr`, except it sucks horrifically. There's a reason `unique_ptr` was created and it's because `auto_ptr` has serious limitations and several nasty surprises.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(myobj)
   return;
```

After object created return proceeded and delete never performed

You need modify code:

```
-if(myobj)
+if(myobj==NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `file1.cpp`

```
Obj* getMyObj();
```

the function is kind of unsafe since the caller of the function needs to know that he must delete the object returned but it is not clear from the function that it is necessary

better is to use a smart pointer like a shared_ptr instead of the raw pointer, it would then be clear that the object returned is allocated on the heap and also how it is destroyed (if allocated).

```
std::shared_ptr<Obj> getMyObj();
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `shared_ptr`, as it has quite specialized and not very versatile semantics.